# Signer attachment types supported

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to restrict the documents types that a signer can upload using the signer attachment?  There does not seem to be a way to do this when setting the template.  I would like to prevent users from uploading exe or other binary files.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way for you to specify which file types to restrict, however the DocuSign platform has certain restrictions already in place.

When you use the `Signer Attachment` tab in your envelopes only file types that are considered "documents" are allowed as attachments, since once you attach them it shows as another page.  Therefore, the recipient can not attach .exes or other binary files.  You should be able to confirm this through some quick tests in the demo (developer) environment.